Best way to create ladder like dataframe using python
I have a list of dataframes:
data1 = {'rec_number': [1, 2, ,3 ,4, 5, 6]}
data2 = {'rec_number': [1, 2, ,3 ,4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
data3 = {'rec_number': [1, 2, ,3 ,4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
lst = [df1, df2, df3]

My list would have thousands of dataframes, each having different 'rec_number', I need to add additional columns to all the dataframes to create a "shift like" columns. (take df1 for example):
data1 = {'rec_number': [1, 2, ,3 ,4, 5, 6], 
'rec_number_2': [np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
'rec_number_3': [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
'rec_number_4': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3], 
'rec_number_5': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2], 
'rec_number_6': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

What would be most efficient way to add those additional columns?
Thanks!

I feel this may be an XY problem, what exactly are you trying to achieve here, and why does it need to be done this way? This scales terribly,  but often in these situations there can be a trick to it

Are the actual rec_numbers sequential numbers like in your example? In other words, can they be replaced by range(1, n)? Or are they just examples and the actual numbers are random?

As @ken mentioned, based on the assumption that the rec_number would be a range, try this for i in range(df.max().tolist()[0]):     df[f"rec_number_{i+1}"] = df.iloc[:, 0].shift(i) and iterate this through all the dataframes.

@fam-woodpecker they are sequential numbers. I am trying to calculate NPV value to each line on a moving way.

@ken They are sequential numbers. I will try replace it with range (1, n) and see if this works.

@rr_goyal I will try this code and see if this works. Thanks!

Can you explain in detail how you would use a ladder-like table to calculate NPV? In terms of efficiency, there may be a better way. If you explain it and we can say there is no better way, I will post my answer for the most efficient method.
